# Migration not working?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration

I just tried to migrate [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68325/physics-tension-question) to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), but it's just ending up closed (and locked) here, without showing up on Physics.SE. I undid it and redid it, with no change. I guess there is some problem with the migration mechanism?

Comment: Is this question: [writing up past maths exam papers for collaboration](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68171/) suffering from a similar issue but this time related to [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Ack, yes it is! I'll unlock it too for the time being.

Comment: It's worth noting the question in the comment above wasn't migrated for the same reason.

Comment: For future reference Physics.SE does not accept elementary exercises in a raw form like that---though we do accept questions on the concepts at play in very simple problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edit] Nope, my fault...moderators used to bypass this tag-exists-on-destination check, this is a bug...one that'll be fixed in a build shortly.